# How do I determine the running time for each line in terms of 'n' for a program? And total Big-O running time for whole program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, big-o, cumulative-sum

I missed class the day we went over big O notation and haven't really been able to catch up. I'm just confused on what the running time is for each line of code in terms of n, and the total big O running time for the whole program.

I've tried using websites but it's still confusing.

```
filename = input("Please enter file name: ")
file = open(filename, "r")
number = int(file.readline())

for line in file.readlines():
    new_number = int(line)
    if number > new_number:
        print ("Looks like", filename, "needs to be sorted")
        break
    number = new_number
else:
    print ("Congratulations! The file", filename, "is nicely sorted!")

file.close()
```

The results should be in the format of n. for example, O(n) or O(n^2)

Comment: Maybe time the execution for a small number of `n`, then a larger number of `n` then a huge number of `n` and see how it scales with `n` ... https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: What are your guesses? We can't teach you all of Big-O analysis here, and it's a bit much to ask us to go over every single line of code. Show us what you know already and what you think the answers are. We can help you cross the finish line.

Comment: you normally dont analyse each line but instead discard constants like your first line is a constant no matter the size of `n` so doesnt need to be evaluated. In your worst case here you have a file of `n` lines and assuming the worst case you will iterate over every line......so your worst run time is `n`

Comment: I guess I'm just confused about how to analyze the running time of opening a file and things like that. Is the total Big-O notation just the highest value term, such as n^2 or log2n (just examples, not my actual solution)?

Comment: Questions about theoretical computer science (as opposed to questions about the practice of writing software) don't belong on Stack Overflow in the first place -- that's why [cs.se] exists.

Answer (score 0):

Big O analysis is used to give an idea of how a program scales as user input changes.

Lets start with basics:

```
def foo(user_input):

       output = 5+5

       return output
```

The above example shows that no matter how big my user input is, whether it is 5 or 5 billion, my program will run at a constant "speed". This is O(1) where 1 represents a constant.

```
def foo(user_input):

    for i in range(user_input):
             print(i)
```

Now what is happening here is that the time it takes to run our program is determined by the length of input. If we have a large input, it takes a large time to run, small input takes small time to run. The correlation is such that time to run is equal to our user_input. Hence big O is O(n) where n is length of user input.

```
filename = input("Please enter file name: ")
file = open(filename, "r")
number = int(file.readline())

for line in file.readlines():
    new_number = int(line)
    if number > new_number:
        print ("Looks like", filename, "needs to be sorted")
        break
    number = new_number
     else:
        print ("Congratulations! The file", filename, "is nicely sorted!")

file.close()
```

The length of user input is directly determined by how many lines there are in the file. If there are n lines in the file, it would run n times. Hence big O is O(n).

Now you may be asking, "what about the IF statement and printing? It also adds time to the program even if its nanoseconds of time"

Anything else that you are doing in the for loop does not change with user input. In fact, it's constant. So it would be written as O(n+1). But the fact is, if n is a million, million+1 is irrelevant as it takes practically the same time. Hence we ignore any constants ( including multiplicative constants such as O(3n)) to result in O(n).

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point about questions which "are not about programming as defined in the help center". That definition focuses on questions about the *practice* of programming, not computer science theory -- the latter has its own Stack Exchange site, at [cs.se].